# Text dragging in touch devices KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

I am working with creating a library for image editing using KineticJS. In it, a text should be on the image. On a canvas,  Kinetic stage is creating and then image and text are added as layers. Am extending the Kinetic.Text here. Text adding is working fine.

The issue is related to the dragging of the added text. In touch devices, the added text is draggable only when touch and drag on a portion little far to bottom side, not exactly on the top of it. But no issues in desktop browsers.